# Does Gdal read temporary files?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to change geographic reference system images from landsat 8. I created one method to do it in my class. I used the temporary directory as strategy to convert files and clean all row rasters the routine has converted. However I had this error in my script (`sh: 1: cannot open TemporaryDirectory: No such file`). Does gdal read temporary files? Why does my code show up this error?

```
def change_src_from_lc8_image(self):

    tmp = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    output_folder_reprojetcted = '{}/{}'.format(self.tmp,self.file_name_targz)

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder_reprojetcted):
        os.mkdir('{}/{}'.format(self.tmp, self.file_name_targz))

    with tarfile.open(self.raster_file_path_targz, "r") as tar:
        tar.extractall('{}/'.format(tmp))

    list_raster_folder = glob('{}{}'.format(tmp, '/*/*TIF'))

    for tif in list_raster_folder:
        command = "gdalwarp {img_src} {img_output} -s_srs EPSG:32624 t_srs EPSG:4674".format(img_src=tif, img_output=output_folder_reprojetcted)
        os.system(command)

    tmp.cleanup()
```

Comment: Did you know you can use in-memory raster datasets?: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html

Comment: I didn't. Do you you know any example?

Comment: Here are a few links that may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/264793/8104 and using rasterio https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/memory-files.html

Comment: Are you sure this is GDAL error ``sh: 1: cannot open TemporaryDirectory: No such file``. It seems to me, error is in this line ``tmp = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()``. The tempfile.TemporaryDirectory available in python 3.2 or higher. For instance try to use just '/tmp' folder.

Comment: I can't make a comment yet, otherwise I would put this there, but I think your `gdalwarp` command is also incorrect, which could cause a file to not be found. Your `t_srs` switch should be `-t_srs`.